# Java 8 Nashorn load script without executing it

Tags: nashorn

I am using Java 8 Nashorn to execute a specific previously agreeed upon method.  I could Invoke the specific method no problem.  One thing that bugged me though is that when I load the script, it also executes it.

For example if file.js contains a print("hello world!") the scriptEngine.eval(new FileReader("./file.js") would execute and print hello world. I have to do this before I could invoke the specific method I want.

Is there a way to eval()/load the scripts without executing it?

Thanks

Comment: *"Is there a way to load the scripts without executing it?"* What would be the result of this operation? Do you just want to get the source text? In that case, just read the file with `FileReader`?

Comment: I wanted to eventually Invoke a specific method, but I am unable to do that without previously calling .eval() which executes the script :(

Answer (score 2):

turns out You could do this by Casting engine to Compilable then call the compile function.

```
final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
final Compilable compilable = (Compilable) engine;
        final Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        final String statement = "function fetch(values) { return values['first_name'] + ' ' + values['last_name']; };";
        final CompiledScript compiled = compilable.compile(statement);
```

This achieved what I want without needing to eval() it